# Is it possible to read a file in a shared network folder from Windows 10 IOT?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

From my app, I need to get a file saved in a shared folder, in a local area network. In my dev computer, for Windows 10, I use FileOpenPicker, so the user give permission to the app to access to the file, and finally I use StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList to do it permanent.

Moving it to Windows 10 IOT, it does not work. FileOpenPicker is not supported and then I cannot get access to the file, even the app know the path.

The project is based in 30 raspberry units that need to get a file generated by a PC. They basically refresh monitors every 5 minutes, like arrival/departure monitors in a airport. I am thinking to share the file using REST but I was wondering if there is a way to do it directly via sharing folders.

Comment: Very curious, have the same issue

Comment: After my research, the only way I have found is to create a rest server to access to the file. A oversized solution but at least it works.